# Part of model in Unity is inside out but not in Blender?

Tags: unity, blender, models

I've downloaded this [asset](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/drugdor-the-golem-animated-19c1855bdb2c4cdc89da2cfb64da48cf) and it looks perfectly fine in preview, and even in blender.

[image]

But when I import it in Unity, one of its shoulder is inside out, even after making all faces double sided.

[image]

I also tried switching the normal mode in the import settings to Calculate.

[image]

What causes this issue and how could I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us the shader/material you're using to render this?

Comment: I'm using Unity's Standard material, everything is set to default, only the Albedo Map is set as the provided one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you view the model in the Sketchfap viewer, click on the "Model Inspector" button and then enable "Vertex Normals", then you can see that the right shoulder of that character indeed has inward-facing normals. This is a mistake in the model, not with the way you import it. Such a mistake is easy to make, because many 3d modeling programs have two-sized rendering enabled by default (to improve usability), while most game engines do not (to improve performance).

You should be able to fix that in Blender by selecting the shoulder and [flip the normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/105135).

But if you really don't want to mess with the model and use it as it is, then another option is to use a shader which supports two-sided rendering. How to find/create such a shader depends on what render pipeline you are using.